# HAML ruby logic in script tag not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

How can I get the following if statement to evaluate correctly in HAML?

```
# "throws JS error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token -" and does not evaluate the if statement

:javascript
  angular.module("userFromServer", [])
    .constant("currentUser", {
      ENV: "#{Rails.env}",
      - if logged_in
        name: "#{@User.name}",
    })

# this works

:javascript
  angular.module("userFromServer", [])
    .constant("currentUser", {
      ENV: "#{Rails.env}",
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put:

```
:javascript
  angular.module("userFromServer", [])
    .constant("currentUser", {
      name: "#{@User.try(:name)}",
      ENV: "#{Rails.env}",
    })
```

If @user is nil, your stuff won't blow up. You could also extract that out into it's own method helper, but that should get you by for now.

Comment: I guess you could, but I also have some @user.profile.something methods so it'd start to get messy...